# Rails Routing Help for Dashboard Namespace

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, routes, admin, dashboard

I think I have everything set up correctly, but when I try to visit the dashboards_posts_path it directs to the dashboard_path view instead of app>views>dashboards>posts#index view. I'm not understanding why.

[router](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UN8hJ.png)

```
namespace :dashboards do
 resources :posts
 resources :tags
 resources :ingredients
 resources :comments
 resources :pages
 resources :users
end
```

[controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AW1cA.png)

```
class Dashboards::PostsController < DashboardsController
 # before_action :admin_authorize, only: [:new, :create, :edit, :update, :destroy]
 protect_from_forgery with: :null_session
 layout "dashboards"

 def current_user
  if session[:user_id]
   @current_user = User.find(session[:user_id])
  end
 end

 def index
  @posts = Post.newest.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 3)
  @all_posts = Post.all
 end
end
```

[views](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h0BAR.png)

[routes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xo3wJ.jpg)

[log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K1ibW.png)

Comment: Can you show the logs, specifically the GET requests? because I have a feeling that dashoards_posts_path is actually redirecting to dashboards_path. i.e. if you have some before_action in your ApplicationController that does some redirection; i.e. authorization

Comment: added photo under "log" it's definitely redirecting, I just can't see why? I don't understand why it's being processed by the dashboards controller instead of the dashboards/posts controller.

Comment: That fixed it right up! Thank you so much!!

Comment: Also, please remember to post code, not images. If you post images, we can't copy and paste to show where problems might exist.

Comment: BTW, there is no redirect in your log image.

Comment: ok, yes this makes sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that your defined `resources :dashboard` before all your `namespace :dashboards` stuff (I'm speculating). Remember, routes resolve top to bottom. So, routing resolves `GET dashboards/posts` to `dashboards/:id` which is why you're routing to `DashboardsController#show` with and `id` of `posts`.

Why don't you try:

```
resources :dashboards do
  resources :posts
  resources :tags
  resources :ingredients
  resources :comments
  resources :pages
  resources :users
end
```

Which should resolve correctly.

Alternatively, put `resources :dashboards` *after* your namespace stuff, like this:

```
namespace :dashboards do
  resources :posts
  resources :tags
  resources :ingredients
  resources :comments
  resources :pages
  resources :users
end

resources :dashboards
```

Comment: It won't let me upvote you because I'm still so new, but you've been upvoted in my heart!